# Unable to comunicate to Arduino Uno on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, arduino

I have installed the Arduino ide 1.6.9 by downloading it from Arduino website. When I plug the Arduino UNO board the LEDs on it turn on.

When I try to upload a program to the board it says:

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "COM1": No such file or
>   directory ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device

The menu item tools>ports is grayed out.

I have tried plugging and unplugging the board with the ide open and closed without success.

The output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.  Bus 001 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 003 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 002 Device 004: ID
0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.  Bus 002
Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

No difference in the outputs of `lsusb` and `dmesg` with the Arduino plugged and unplugged.

I have no clue on what to do!

Comment: COM ports are Windows. You want /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyUSB0 on Linux

Comment: Reviewers: OP posted an answer, saying the hardware was defect.

Answer (score 2):

You said it's showing up as a COM device on linux, but from my experience with arduino devices and linux, it should show up as an ACM device instead. The setup posted on the ardunio Web page should show this as well.

Here is the setup for windows:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Windows

Here is the setup for linux:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#toc7

The first thing I would do is ensure that you followed the getting started steps properly. Most specifically, take a good look at step 7 that has you select your board type. Notice right underneath it it also lists your board port, which is where I think your issue lies. Try to see if you can change that detail.

Edit: missed the part where you said it is greyed out

Here is another post that has a lot of "solutions" where something should work for you. From what it looks the quickest test method would be to launch the ide with root permissions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322432/arduino-tools-serial-port-greyed-out

Comment: stackoverflow link helps alot.

"sudo arduino" worked for me

Comment: `sudo arduino` is unnecessary if your user belongs to `dialout` group (which is one of the things you should do when setting up any user for working with most embedded devices connecting via serial USB like microcontrollers or FPGAs), since `/dev/ttyACM0` and related serial devices all belong to `root` user and `dialout` group.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but apparently the arduino board I was trying to talk to was damaged. I connect to another one at first try without changing anything...